# Regex find find files containing multiple controllers/directives in angular files

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

So this is working on regexr.com `angular.module[\S\s]+?\.(controller|directive)[\S\s]+?\.(controller|directive)`

Unfortunately, in vscode file search, it seems to ignore the second part of the controller|directive match and returns any file with at least one `.(controller|directive)`

What am I doing wrong here? I expect using the above regex in global file search to return files that have multiple directives/components in the same file like the below example.

```
angular.module( 'myModule' )
    .directive( 'myDirective',
        [ function ( ) { ... } ])
    .controller('myComponent',
        [ function ( ) { ... } ]);
```

However, I'm getting all files back with only one like this.

```
angular.module( 'myModule' )
    .directive( 'myDirective',
        [ function ( ) { ... } ]);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you expect it to match and how you're using it in vscode?

Comment: Updated my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code doesn't support multiline search, so it will just test that regex on each line. I actually just added a note about this to our docs: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/commit/44cf2ee27a8ce164b61c9c096359506cb1a8809b

If the file is open, it will actually pull the matches from the editor, which does support multiline search. (Just a note in case you see it work sometimes).